# Oracle pre-compiler (pro*c) not working on centos

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, centos, precompile

I have installed oracle 11g XE Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit and sqlplus runs fine on this (directory --> **/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin**)  +

---

I have also installed separately oracle instant client -basic and devel both 11.2.0.2.0 (in **/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64**) and upgraded the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as -----> **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=ls /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib** & then export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib.

Now on running a sample program by this: proc i**name=hellodb.pc MODE=ORACLE**    it says Proc command not found.

Comment: You need to include the path of pro*c executable to the PATH variable(by modifying the ~/.bashrc file), because the proc command is not resolving. Suggest you to follow this [Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/proc/proc.htm). You can search for the path of pro\*c  by doing `find / -name "proclab*"`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you have installed package "instantclient-precomp-linux-x86-64-11.2.0.2.0.zip" witch contains pro*c ? If so, than probably,  directory containing binaries of oracle instant client is missing from your PATH variable